# Microsoft Graph API - paging large collections

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm just looking at the Microsoft Graph API PHP SDK to get a bunch of resources, notably Users.

Looking a the SDK docs, there's 2 ways to get users, one using the `createRequest()` method and the other using the `createCollectionRequest()` method.

The docs suggests using the `createCollectionRequest()` and then just doing a while loop, `array_merge` and `getPage()` to create an array.

```
while (!$docGrabber->isEnd()) {
  $docs = array_merge($docs,$docGrabber->getPage());
}
```

The issue is, I have a collection of ~50,000 users, so this method isn't particularly efficient.

I guess the biggest issue, i that the above example (using the while loop) is to avoid using the `@odata.nextLink` that the API returns.

But, what if we actually want to use this, instead of returning every single record in a single array?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using getPage() and that sample, you can access the nextlink with something like this:

```
$url = "/users";

// Get the first page
$response = $graph->createCollectionRequest("GET", $url)
                   ->setPageSize(50)
                   ->execute();

if ($response->getNextLink())
{
    $url = $response->getNextLink();
    // TODO: remove https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0 part of nextlink
} else {
// There are no more pages.
    return null;
}

// get the next page, page size is already set in the next link
$response = $graph->createCollectionRequest("GET", $url)
                  ->execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to my question. It would seem that the `$response` is an array, so calling the `getNextLink()` throws an error: `Call to a member function getNextLink() on array`. I'm using v1.9 of the SDK

Comment: My mistake. We need to remove the setReturnType method call. Updated the example. After the GraphResponse is returned, then call getResponseAsObject()